# Rails - Routing Error for the POST method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Rails newbie here (trying to get these questions answered)

I'm using Ryan Bates' Rails Cast on Wicked Wizard Forms to create a multi-step form. I'm getting a "No route matches [POST] "/user_steps/gender" (where gender is a view under the user_steps controller).

Any ideas?

routes.rb:

```
Store::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :likes

  resources :categories


  resources :users
  resources :user_steps

  root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

user_steps controller:

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard
    steps :gender, :items, :brands, :final

    def show
        render_wizard
    end 

    def update
        @user.attributes = params[:user]
        render_wizard
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define a new method, rails will default to a get request on that method.  In order to make it a post method, try adding

```
match "user_steps/gender", to: "user_steps#gender", via: "post"
```

Check out [this routes reference](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/)

Comment: This works - now I'm getting `No route matches {:controller=>"user_steps", :action=>"show", :id=>nil}` Is the `user.id` not being passed properly?

Comment: When/where are you getting that error?  If you're also trying to render the partial via a get request, then you should add `get` to the `via` hash

Comment: This is a routing error AFTER submitting the 'gender' view. My log shows that the user.id is actually not being passed upon rendering the gender view.

Comment: I think you would have to post some more code for that.  If Rails is telling you that your users id is nil, it is.  There is a variable that isn't getting set properly.  I would debug that by calling something like `raise params[:user].inspect`, and if it doesn't look right, follow the stack to figure out why.

Answer (score 4):

I'm looking for rails wizards solutions and was going through "#346 Wizard Forms with Wicked" railscas when I ran into the same issue.

Adding a route, as @Klipfel suggests, is a good "rails" answer but not the correct approach for the wicked gem. If you add a route pointing to another controller method you are routing the request outside of the wicked framework.

I resolved this problem by specifying put for the http method. In the #346 Wizard Forms with Wicked railscast case it would look like this:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>
```

I'm not sure why it works in the railscast

Comment: this is a good answer, but I think in Rails 4.1+ it should now be method: :patch (at least that is what I see in the routes, and that is what I put in the form_for and it worked)